# Wr discuss with our teachers for one case.We negotiate with our teachers for one case

Tags: differences, word-usage

We discuss with our teachers for one case.  Wr negotiate with our teachers for one case. 
Which one is correct? Clarify the difference between them? 
I think  2nd one is correct. 
The 1st one needs an object for discuss is a transitive verb.

Comment: Discussing and negotiating are usually different things. You can *discuss* quantum theory, for example, purely to explore the subject, whereas *negotiating* usually means you have a list of things you *hope to obtain*, and you're attempting to reach some *compromise* with whoever has the ability to give them to you, or otherwise help you. I don't think your *for one case* fits very well for either context.

Comment: Please clear it clearly.

Comment: @user124234 What? "Please clear it clearly" doesn't make sense. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Discussing is simply talking over. Let's say in the scenario you received a test score you are unhappy with. Discussing might mean that you go in to see the teacher, you talk about your score, and they might tell you how to do better in the future.

Negotiating with your teacher over the score would mean you ask for ten points extra credit, they disagree, and then they offer you three points. It is like negotiating a price on a car, you and the vendor almost "argue" it out until you've both reached a desirable deal.

Now in your example, you are saying negotiating for 'one case'. If you could clarify what the case is, then the verb choice would be more obvious.

Comment: I am confused.  I am trying to ask you about my sentences. Yo teachers are explaining nouns.  Like negotiating etc. Please clear my concept.

Comment: If you could clarify what 'the case' is that the 'teacher' is discussing, then we would be able to give you a solid answer.

Comment: in which case "negotiating with a teacher over a grade' is the correct usage